nfs "no route to host" in 24.10
After upgrading my server and client to 24.10 nfs has stopped working.
The error I get is "no route to host" which seems to be related to the firewall blocking port 2049 and in fact trying traceroute to the server I get this:
traceroute to 192.168.41.45 (192.168.41.45), 64 hops max
  1   192.168.41.45  2.660ms !X  0.922ms !X  0.982ms !X 

where !X means something is wrong.
The strange thing is that even if I disable ufw I still get the same error.
The firewall seems to be configured OK: I can ssh into the server on port 22 and rules are in place for nfs on port 2049 from the clients:
me@server:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2049                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
2049                       ALLOW       192.168.41.0/24           
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
111                        ALLOW       192.168.41.0/24           
13025                      ALLOW       192.168.41.0/24           
2049 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

Port 2049 is open
Starting Nmap 7.94SVN ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-10-25 17:56 BST
Nmap scan report for zbox (192.168.41.45)
Host is up (0.000072s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
2049/tcp open  nfs

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.11 seconds

Don't think it is a problem with NFS because I can mount the shares on the server.
Any clue what the problem could be? (note: prior the upgrade everything was OK).
